# Bootstrap - two images not showing up while others are.

Tags: php, image, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out why two images are not showing up. Every other image is. I've look over the code many times and have deleted classes, change the png's to jpegs and other hacky tests and nothing has worked. I feel it's something obvious but I am not seeing it. 
I know the links are correct because it is showing up in Safari in both my test server and online server. All other browsers it is not. Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks, Jacob

The page
http://jacobnorwood.com/campaign_roger_beasley_mazda.php

```
<!-- Column 1 Start -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 m-b-global">
<h2>Mazda 6 300x250 Video</h2>
        <a id="mazda6_300x250" href="campaign_rb_mazda_300_250_vid.php" title="Mazda 6 300x250 with Video">
            <img src="_/images/rb_red_300x250_1.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Mazda 6 300x250" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Column 1 End -->
    <!-- Column 2 Start -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 m-b-global m-top-ad">
        <a href="campaign_rb_mazda_300_250_vid.php" title="Mazda 6 300x250">
            <img src="_/images/rb_red_300x250_2.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Mazda 6 300x250 with Video" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Column 2 End -->
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Idk why but "It's blocked by client"
Try changing path or changing name.
also check if you have any kind of protection that limits bandwidth and/or upload limit.

Comment: Thanks, Your hint help me figure out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was the Ad Block Plus extension. I had "300x250" in the image link and caused it to block the image.

Comment: Always disable all browser extensions when debugging Web problems :-)